# Spoken English in real life

Tags: spoken-english, informal-language, formal-language

I will appreciate it if somebody could help me find an answer:
Is there a difference between English language studied as a foreign language (as in books and references made to study it as a foreign or second language) and the spoken English language in real life (as in movies)?

I am an intermediate level English learner and I wish to be fluent in English in order to be able to communicate in English fluently, so I need to know what I should do to get my spoken english as a native speaker
(note: I don't have the chance to immerse myself in English speaking community)

Comment: It would depend on which books and references the language programs use.  Some countries have old and outdated texts, and teach "dry" vocabulary and grammar rules that don't really help the student speak like a native.  However the only real solution is to immerse yourself in an English-speaking culture, either by living in an English-speaking country or by having many English-speaking friends.

Comment: Well I wouldn't call the movies "real life", but day-to-day language is highly situational. You might learn the best book learning but often that is not how people actually speak. In a native language sense, we learn by copying others (from infancy), and then fill it in with all that "grammar" stuff. As such, I think immersion is the best way to accomplish what you want, but expect it could take years. Keep in mind native speakers have 15+ years of experience even before college.

Comment: You should ask about "spoken English language in real life" and "to be able to easily read academic subjects and books" in separate questions since the approach to improve in these areas will be different.

Comment: Spoken languages are *always* different from textbook languages. Textbooks want you to learn "by the book" (with few exceptions) while the people you meet speak something entirely different. True story: In my 20s I got a job with a German bank, speaking textbook German (learned in high school and university), which the VP praised highly. After a couple months I'd picked up a lot of "real" German and when I saw that VP again I showed off what I had learned, expecting further praise. Instead he gave me a quizzical look and lamented that my German seemed to have gone to hell.

Comment: @user3169   I did edit my question..thank You... but how does the English spoken in movies differ from real life ?

Comment: English spoken in movies may differ in real life. It just depends who might be speaking; where the movie may take place; the culture; a lot of things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I agree with Andrew's comments. There are many technical grammar books out there, but you really need to be given an opportunity to **apply** your knowledge in real life situations.

Here is some advice to help:

1. Try to find friends to practice with.  ( worth saying again).
2. Listen to English movies and TV especially if they have subtitles in your language.
3. Listen to the radio and programmes on the internet. The BBC has excellent programmes which are available by internet throughout the world.
4. Watch and listen to YouTube.

5.Read, Read ,Read.  Reading helps you to increase your vocabulary and to learn 
new grammar structures.  Use google to find novels that are appropriate for your level and find a book that interests you.

**MOST IMPORTANT**

**Use all of the above methods to apply your textbook knowledge of English.  For example, if you are studying adverbs then listen for them while you watch a film or listen to the radio.**.  Make a note what adverbs they use and also how and when they use them.  Do the same for verb structures and so on.

Learning from a grammar book is ok, but you need to see how English grammar functions.

I hope that helps a little.

6.